# which indexes multiple field?

Tags: mysql

I have a question for field indexing and I am not really sure how to do it.
Which indexes should be multiple field index and which "stand alone"...sorry for my terminology :).

I have a table where only insert,delete and select will be present, only a104 will be updatable, other fields will be "read only"...
So I have 106 fields and data 105 fields will never change. Once the record is in the table it will stay unchanged...only after few days it will move to archive table.
(Insert, delete, select with where will be present...). I will have simple and detail search page for searching the records. Insert frequency I suppose up to 2500 per day...
Delete up to 1000 records per day...for now...

Simple search will have select like this:

SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE ad2='yyy' and ad4='qqq' (where part will always start with ad2 ! other field could be left...I suppose one index wiil be
for this two fields: KEY `firstindex` (`ad2`,`ad4`)

Advanced search will user few more fields in WHERE clause... a1,a2,a3,a4,a25,a26,a27,a28,a31,a32,a33,a35, and everything from a41 to a101 -->these all are bit fields

All mentioned fields in simple and advanced search will contain data which will never change, only after while records will be deleted (moved to archive table...)
So my question is how to set up indexes in my case to get best performance for select and compromise for insert and delete...

This is my MyISAM table....(not really small one)

---

CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `a1` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `a2` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `a3` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `a4` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `a5` varchar(60) NOT NULL default '',
  `a6` varchar(60) NOT NULL default '',
  `a7` varchar(15) NOT NULL default '',
  `a8` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `a9` varchar(60) NOT NULL default '',
  `a10` varchar(20) NOT NULL default '',
  `a11` varchar(60) NOT NULL default '',
  `a12` varchar(60) NOT NULL default '',
  `a13` varchar(60) NOT NULL default '',
  `a14` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `a15` varchar(60) NOT NULL default '',
  `a16` varchar(60) NOT NULL default '',
  `a17` varchar(15) NOT NULL default '',
  `a18` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `a19` varchar(60) NOT NULL default '',
  `a20` varchar(11) NOT NULL default '',
  `a21` varchar(60) NOT NULL default '',
  `a22` varchar(60) NOT NULL default '',
  `a23` varchar(60) NOT NULL default '',
  `a24` varchar(60) NOT NULL default '',
  `a25` date NOT NULL,
  `a26` time NOT NULL,
  `a27` date NOT NULL,
  `a28` time NOT NULL,
  `a29` decimal(2,0) NOT NULL default '0',
  `a30` decimal(25,6) NOT NULL default '0.000000',
  `a31` bit(1) NOT NULL,
  `a32` decimal(2,0) NOT NULL default '0',
  `a33` decimal(52,6) NOT NULL default '0.000000',
  `a34` varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
  `a35` varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
  `a36` varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
  `a37` varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
  `a38` varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
  `a39` varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
  `a40` varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
  `a41` bit(1) NOT NULL default '\0',
  `a42` bit(1) NOT NULL default '\0',
  `a43` bit(1) NOT NULL default '\0',
  `a44` bit(1) NOT NULL default '\0',
  `a45` bit(1) NOT NULL default '\0',
  `a46` bit(1) NOT NULL default '\0',
  `a47` bit(1) NOT NULL default '\0',
  `a48` bit(1) NOT NULL default '\0',
  `a49` bit(1) NOT NULL default '\0',
  `a50` bit(1) NOT NULL default '\0',
  `a51` bit(1) NOT NULL default '\0',
  `a52` bit(1) NOT NULL default '\0',
  `a53` bit(1) NOT NULL default '\0',
  `a54` bit(1) NOT NULL default '\0',
  `a55` bit(1) NOT NULL default '\0',
  `a56` bit(1) NOT NULL default '\0',
  `a57` bit(1) NOT NULL default '\0',
  `a58` bit(1) NOT NULL default '\0',
  `a59` bit(1) NOT NULL default '\0',
  `a60` bit(1) NOT NULL default '\0',
  `a61` bit(1) NOT NULL default '\0',
  `a62` bit(1) NOT NULL default '\0',
  `a63` bit(1) NOT NULL default '\0',
  `a64` bit(1) NOT NULL default '\0',
  `a65` bit(1) NOT NULL default '\0',
  `a66` bit(1) NOT NULL default '\0',
  `a67` bit(1) NOT NULL default '\0',
  `a68` bit(1) NOT NULL default '\0',
  `a69` bit(1) NOT NULL default '\0',
  `a70` bit(1) NOT NULL default '\0',
  `a71` bit(1) NOT NULL default '\0',
  `a72` bit(1) NOT NULL default '\0',
  `a73` bit(1) NOT NULL default '\0',
  `a74` bit(1) NOT NULL default '\0',
  `a75` bit(1) NOT NULL default '\0',
  `a76` bit(1) NOT NULL default '\0',
  `a77` bit(1) NOT NULL default '\0',
  `a78` bit(1) NOT NULL default '\0',
  `a79` bit(1) NOT NULL default '\0',
  `a80` bit(1) NOT NULL default '\0',
  `a81` bit(1) NOT NULL default '\0',
  `a82` bit(1) NOT NULL default '\0',
  `a83` bit(1) NOT NULL default '\0',
  `a84` bit(1) NOT NULL default '\0',
  `a85` bit(1) NOT NULL default '\0',
  `a86` bit(1) NOT NULL default '\0',
  `a87` bit(1) NOT NULL default '\0',
  `a88` bit(1) NOT NULL default '\0',
  `a89` bit(1) NOT NULL default '\0',
  `a90` bit(1) NOT NULL default '\0',
  `a91` bit(1) NOT NULL default '\0',
  `a92` bit(1) NOT NULL default '\0',
  `a93` bit(1) NOT NULL default '\0',
  `a94` bit(1) NOT NULL default '\0',
  `a95` bit(1) NOT NULL default '\0',
  `a96` bit(1) NOT NULL default '\0',
  `a97` bit(1) NOT NULL default '\0',
  `a98` bit(1) NOT NULL default '\0',
  `a99` bit(1) NOT NULL default '\0',
  `a100` bit(1) NOT NULL default '\0',
  `a101` bit(1) NOT NULL default '\0',
  `a102` text NOT NULL,
  `a103` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `a104` enum('a','n','r') NOT NULL,
  `a105` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
`) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=0 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;`

---

Thanks!

Comment: What are you storing that could possible require such a hidious schema?

Answer (score 0):

Indexes should be created based on your queries, as you said and if I have not misunderstood You mostly apply query having where on a2 and a4..

so as u supposed you can use indexing on these two field.

and as u said in advanced query, you are using mostly all or many more fields.

you should not use indexing on this much fields as that will be not much effective than without any indexes.

as indexing on these much fields increase load on insert and delete queries.

so you can use indexing on mostly used fields like a2 and a4 or leave it.